# How to save text box values in MS Word from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I have two text boxes and one button in my aspx page. When I click on the button, the Word document should open and the text box values should be stored in the Word document.

Comment: Not enough info. Please supply more background - What word document? where- On the server, on or the client machines? which browsers does this need to work on?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have to download Open Xml SDK.
Than you will be able to create a word documents from your asp page.

some tutorials:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd440953%28v=office.12%29.aspx

something like this:

```
    using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(docName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) 
  {
    // Add a new main document part. 
    package.AddMainDocumentPart(); 

    // Create the Document DOM. 
    package.MainDocumentPart.Document = 
      new Document( 
        new Body( 
          new Paragraph( 
            new Run( 
              new Text("Hello World!"))))); 

    // Save changes to the main document part. 
    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save(); 
  }
```

then you have to write the word document to the response stream.
something like this:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(PathToExcelFile);
if (file.Exists)
{
   Response.Clear();
   Response.ClearHeaders();
   Response.ClearContent();
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
   Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
   Response.End();
}
else
{
   Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
}
```

Comment: +1, but perhaps you should change the type from `Excel` to `Word`

Comment: sorry, I just copied the snippet from somewhere. But It should be clear what is going on here..